# How to concatenate input name attributes on submit?

Tags: jquery, shopify

I'm trying to capture the date of birth of the customers on registration. Following user registration, a customer object is created in the store admin (Shopify) with the corresponding information applied to the notes field. The problem is the UI asks for 3 separate fields (day, month, year) and this is the way the information is being displayed in admin:

- dob_day: DD
- dob_month: MM
- dob_year: YYYY

Is there a way to concatenate the input name attributes on submit to show the date of birth in the following format: DD/MM/YYYY

```
<div id="dob" class="clearfix form-row">
  <label for="dob" class="login">Date Of Birth</label>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="DD" name="customer[note][dob_day]" id="dob_day" class="large"/> <span>&#47;</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="MM" name="customer[note][dob_month]" id="dob_month" class="large"/> <span>&#47;</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY" name="customer[note][dob_year]" id="dob_year" class="large"/>
</div>
```

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like this.

```
var day = $('input[name="customer[note][dob_day]"]').val();
var month = $('input[name="customer[note][dob_month]"]').val();
var year = $('input[name="customer[note][dob_year]"]').val();
var dob = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
```

if you want the dob in date format you could also parse it to date format.